# Sagemaker - Distributed training

Tags: machine-learning, distributed-computing, amazon-sagemaker

I can’t find documentation on the behavior of Sagemaker when distributed training is not explicitly specified.

Specifically,

1. When SageMaker distributed data parallel is used via distribution=‘dataparallel’ , documents state that each instance processes different batches of data.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

estimator = TensorFlow(
    role=role,
    py_version="py37",
    framework_version="2.4.1",
    # For training with multinode distributed training, set this count. Example: 2
    instance_count=4,
    instance_type="ml.p3.16xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    # Training using SMDataParallel Distributed Training Framework
    distribution={"smdistributed": {"dataparallel": {"enabled": True}}},
)
```

2. I am not sure what happens when distribution parameter is not specified but instance_count > 1 as below

```
estimator = TensorFlow(
    py_version="py3",
    entry_point="mnist.py",
    role=role,
    framework_version="1.12.0",
    instance_count=4,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the [training code](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/training/distributed_training/tensorflow/data_parallel/mnist/code/train_tensorflow_smdataparallel_mnist.py), when you initialize smdataparallel you get a run time error - RuntimeError: smdistributed.dataparallel cannot be used outside smddprun for distributed training launch.

The distribution parameters you pass in the estimator select the appropriate [runner](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_training/runner.py).

Answer (score 0):

*"I am not sure what happens when distribution parameter is not specified but instance_count > 1 as below"* -> SageMaker will run your code on 4 machines. Unless you have code purpose-built for distributed computation this is useless (simple duplication).

It gets really interesting when:

- you parse resource configuration (resourceconfig.json or via env variables) so that each machine is aware of its rank in the cluster, and you can write custom arbitrary distributed things
- if you run the same code over input that is `ShardedByS3Key`, your code will run on different parts of your S3 data that is homogeneously spread over machines. Which makes SageMaker Training/Estimators a great place to run arbitrary shared-nothing distributed tasks such as file transformations and batch inference.

Having machines clustered together also allows you to launch open-source distributed training software like PyTorch DDP